# How does CallerMemberName work from inside?

Tags: c#, attributes

I cannot find any documentation or at least an explanation of how attributes like this work from inside.

```
    [CallerMemberName] 
    [CallerFilePath] 
    [CallerLineNumber]
```

[Documentation I found](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/caller-information) shows only how to use it.

Is it possible to create your own implementation of [CallerMemberNameAttribute] or some custom [CallerObjectAttribute]?

It's interesting for me just for learning purposes and understanding of the code behind.

Comment: [Here's](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/CallerMemberNameAttribute.cs,50518bb736888186) the reference. Look at the `AttributeUsage`...

Comment: Then look [at](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/attribute.cs,707d3dbc6c887265) the `Attribute` class, this is the base for `CallerMemberName`; it's all in there.

Comment: The C# compiler knows there attributes and injects the name path and line number accordingly. You could not create such attributes yourself. The magic happens in the compiler, not in the attributes.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes, so if the compiler does it, isn't there a way to register your own attributes and introduce them to the compiler because those ones somehow work and logically I assume it should be possible. Or is it really deep-deep inside and cannot be accessed in any way? Maybe you know any source to read about it?

Comment: You would have to rewrite the compiler. The language C# does not provide such a mechanism. Of course you can declare your own attributes, but then you must use reflection to read them and act accordingly. E.g. you can analyse the properties of an object and for instance print out the values of all the properties having a `PrintAttribute` that you declared. But you cannot have to compiler do it for you.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes You don't have to rewrite the whole compiler, just add what you want: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn is available on github. Apart from that, one _can_ write their own attributes anyway. If it's easy to do what the OP wants is a different matter.

Comment: Also recompiling the source code of the compiler, or understanding and modifying it, is not everybodies favorite solution. As a programmer you can only manually attach data to your own attributes. As for CallerMemberName, the compiler is attaching data for you. So mofiying the compiler would be the only solution to have new attributes "like this".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So just for learning purposes. The attributes itself do nothing to the method itself, but to the way it is called.

If the compiler has to create a call to the method, he checks every parameter, if it has one of theses attributes, if so, it passes the name or the file of the caller as parameter value. It overwrites the default value, by an other default value. The requirement of placing the default parameter there is only, to let the compiler allow you to omit this parameter in first place.

Suppose you have code like this:

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test();
        Test1();
    }

    public static void Test(string name = "")
    {
        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }

    public static void Test1([CallerMemberName] string name = "")
    {
        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }
```

The code generated is the same as for

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test("");
        Test1("Main");
    }
```

You cannot emulate this anyhow with your programming, unless you modify the compiler itself. It's the compiler of the caller who puts in this "Main" string, (or the name of the file currently compiled) if it finds this attribute.

If you pass the value of the parameter explicitly, as on the last line of the code sample, both, the default value and the CallerMemberName Attribute will be ignored.

Comment: Good to know, because my initial thinking was that it uses reflection. So it just generates code with needed values and it means these attributes are not adding any additional complexity to the code. Thanks

Comment: Reflection has no access to it, as it only explores the meta-data, not the stacktrace. The call stack, filled with strings, is only available in trace or debug mode, so in release mode you would have nothing at all. That's why they invented these attributes. It's not reading the stack.